# For Loop range not working: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: loops, for-loop, range

I have the following code which scans a list of raw data and for each line and if date and var (a variant I defined) are correct the row is copied and placed into the correct destination. This line to copy row is commented out. The macro worked but instead of copying the whole row I've now attempted (in the 2 lines above the commented out .copy row) to select only specific cells in the row (cells in iRow and columns M,N,O,Q,R,U,V,AB). I get the error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. I know this is related to the 2 new lines of code I input because previously the code worked fine. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
Sub currentMonthDetail()

Dim csCount As Range
Dim b As Variant
Dim shrow As Long
Dim iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, var As Variant, iDate As Variant
Dim bln As Boolean
Dim s As String
Dim eRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'Import monthly data from GL008 tab to detail-----------------------------------------------------------------

Set csCount = Worksheets("Input").Range("csCount")

Sheets("GL008").Activate

iRowL = Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For iRow = 2 To iRowL
    Sheets("GL008").Activate
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 35)) Then
        bln = False
        var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 35).Value, Worksheets("Input").Columns(3), 0)
        iDate = Sheets("GL008").Cells(iRow, 34)
        If Not CVErr(var) = CVErr(xlErrNA) And iDate = Worksheets("Input").Range("E3") Then
        Sheets("GL008").Activate
        Range("M" & iRow, "N" & iRow, "O" & iRow, "Q" & iRow, "R" & iRow, "U" & iRow, "V" & iRow, "AB" & iRow).copy
        'Sheets("GL008").rows(iRow).copy
        s = Sheets("GL008").Cells(iRow, 35)
        Sheets(s).Activate
        eRow = Sheets(s).Cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets(s).rows(eRow)
        End If
    End If


Next iRow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing lots of cells to `Range`. When you try to do that, it's looking for a top-left start cell, a lower-right end cell, and will make a rectangle selection from one to the other.

Because you're trying to give it 8 separate *parameters*, it can't handle it. You need to give it 1 parameter, which contains the cell list; make them all into one string, and then give that string as one parameter to range.

i.e. put the commas *into* the text.

```
Range("M" & iRow & ",N" & iRow & ",O" & iRow & ",Q" & iRow & ",R" & iRow & ",U" & iRow & ",V" & iRow & ",AB" & iRow).copy
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the clarification and solution. Makes sense and works well.